# Extending AZIndex plugin to use custom post types and custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, columns, custom-post-type-archives

I desperately need to be able to display something exactly like this:

http://bottlesup-07112011.31two.com/bottlesup-retailers/

5 columns of custom post type posts sorted alphabetically by custom taxonomy with paging.

I have seen this plugin AZIndex plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/azindex) but it does not load custom post types or custom taxonomies.  I am willing to sponsor a mod if someone can help out with this asap.  Thanks.

Or help with the raw query code as I am a decent WP coder but not good with column output.

Answer (score 1):

Plugin by default works with two deafult WordPress taxonomies 'category' and 'post_tag '. As you already know WordPress has three built in taxonomies 'category', 'post_tag' and 'link_category'. Further, plugin trace two WordPress post types 'post' (normal posts) and 'page'. When you know this and that, you can easily modify plugin to index your_custom_taxonomy and your custom_post_type.

You need to modify two files: az-index-admin.php and az-index-cache.php. If you don't need to index your posts, the most easiest way to make it work with custom post/taxonomy is to change 'category' into ' your_custom_taxonomy' ($taxonomy), (there is several occurrences in both files) and to change 'post' into 'your_post_type' ($object_type), there is several occurrences in az-index-cache.php. And that's it. Of course, with little extra effort you can add your custom taxonomy (not change 'category') but this is for sure the most easiest way to make it.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/azindex-custom-post-types?replies=3#post-2449358